# MQTT and Python - Keep sending messages

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm using an ESP32 to run a MicroPython code, that sends an MQTT message when it boots.

Now this device is **off ( not plugged to power !!)**, but I still get messages that it gets connected to broker.

1) why does it happen ?

2) what do I need to stop it ?

3) last tries was with QOS=1 or 2, maybe this is causing the problem ? still how do I stop it ?

Guy

> EDIT1  - adding debug out put :

```
guy@lab_pi:~ $ mosquitto_sub -d -t HomePi/Dvir/# 
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending CONNECT
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received CONNACK
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: HomePi/Dvir/#, QoS: 0)
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32', ... (4 bytes))
Down
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Windows/Sonoff1', ... (36 bytes))
[HomePi/Dvir/Windows/All][down] D000
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (69 bytes))
[HomePi/Dvir/Windows/Sonoff1] Connected to MQTT server: 192.168.2.113
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (91 bytes))
[2018-08-27 19:14:25.00] Topic: [HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32_3] Message: Button Switch: [OFF]
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (91 bytes))
[2018-08-27 19:25:03.00] Topic: [HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32_3] Message: Button Switch: [OFF]
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (90 bytes))
[2018-08-27 19:26:46.00] Topic: [HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32_3] Message: Button Switch: [UP]
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (91 bytes))
[2018-08-27 19:26:47.00] Topic: [HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32_3] Message: Button Switch: [OFF]
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (92 bytes))
[2018-08-27 19:26:47.00] Topic: [HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32_3] Message: Button Switch: [DOWN]
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'HomePi/Dvir/Messages', ... (91 bytes))
[2018-08-27 19:26:48.00] Topic: [HomePi/Dvir/Windows/ESP32_3] Message: Button Switch: [OFF]
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi sending PINGREQ
Client mosqsub/2800-lab_pi received PINGRESP
```

Comment: You are going to have to supply a lot more information about your set up here for anybody to be able to help. Specifically where are you seeing  the reports that it's connected to the broker. Include the logs

Comment: I have a raspberry pi, acting as a local broker- is also subscribed to messages sent to that specific topic. From time to time ( few minutes) a message is sent to that topic saying that that specific board is now connected to topic- and it is not.

Comment: Edit the question to Include the details

Comment: But assuming this is mosquitto turn on debug level logging and it will tell you which clientid is publishing the message

Comment: Yes. It is mosquito

Comment: @hardillb - added output: please notice to `[HomePi/Dvir/Windows/Sonoff1] Connected to MQTT server: 192.168.2.113` - this is one disconnedted and going on publishing

Comment: @hardillb - by the way, I see other publishes from disconnected devices : ` ESP32` ( not `ESP32_3`) which is the only one connected while debugging, and `[HomePi/Dvir/Windows/All][down] D000` which came from `Sonoff1`

Comment: You need the log from the broker, not from `mosquitto_sub` to show which client is actually doing the publishing

Comment: @hardillb -  can you please direct how to do it ?